# Return the contiguous block in c

Tags: c, heap-memory

I create an array (`char *charheap;`) of length 32 bytes in the heap, and initialize all the elements to be `\0`. Here is my main function:

```
int main(void) {
   char *str1 = alloc_and_print(5,  "hello");
   char *str2 = alloc_and_print(5,  "brian");
 }

 char *alloc_and_print(int s, const char *cpy) {
   char *ncb = char_alloc(s);// allocate the next contiguous block
   if (ret == NULL) {
    printf("Failed\n");
   } else {
    strcpy(ncb, cpy);
    arr_print();// print the array
  }
  return ncb;
 }
```

Here is what I implement:

```
/char_alloc(s): find the FIRST contiguous block of s+1 NULL ('\0') 
characters in charheap that does not contain the NULL terminator
of some previously allocated string./

char *char_alloc(int s) {
 int len = strlen(charheap);
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  if (charheap[0] == '\0') {
   char a = charheap[0];
   return &a;
 } else if (charheap[i] == '\0') {
   char b = charheap[i+1];
   return &b;
  }
 }
 return NULL;
}
```

Expected Output: (`\` means `\0`)

```
hello\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
hello\brian\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
```

This solution is completely wrong and I just print out two failed. :(

Actually, the `char_alloc` should return a pointer to the start of contiguous block but I don't know how to implement it properly. Can someone give me a hint or clue ?

Comment: charheap[i] instead of charheap[0] ?

Comment: Here `strlen(charheap)` , you have not created or passed any array charheap as you wrote in the question

Comment: You need to make use of size s in the loop check.  Restart a count to s whenever a non-zero is found.

Comment: for loop should be to s, not len.  Put a while loop around the for to count to len and fail if you get to the end.  Reset i if needed.

Comment: @PHIfounder I have created in the heap (see the first sentence) :)

Comment: So my actual question is "how to return a pointer to the start of contiguous block "

Comment: Returning pointer of local variable!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function is returning a pointer to a local variable, therefore the caller receives a pointer to invalid memory. Just return the pointer into the `charheap`, which is what you want.

```
   return &charheap[0];   /* was return &a; which is wrong */

   return &charheap[i+1]; /* was return &b; which is wrong */
```

Your `for` loop uses `i < len` for the terminating condition, but, since `charheap` is `\0` filled, `strlen()` will return a size of `0`. You want to iterate through the whole `charheap`, so just use the size of that array (`32` in this case).

```
  int len = 32; /* or sizeof(charheap) if it is declared as an array */
```

The above two fixes should be enough to get your program to behave as you expect (see [demonstration](http://ideone.com/BrrHUh)).

However, you do not place a check to make sure there is enough room in your heap to accept the allocation check. Your allocation should fail if the distance between the start of the available memory and the end of the `charheap` is less than or equal to the desired size. You can enforce this easily enough by setting the `len` to be the last point you are willing to check before you know there will not be enough space.

```
  int len = 32 - s;
```

Finally, when you try to allocate a third string, your loop will skip over the first allocated string, but will overwrite the second allocated string. Your loop logic needs to change to skip over each allocated string. You first check if the current location in your `charheap` is free or not. If it is not, you advance your position by the length of the string, plus one more to skip over the '\0' terminator for the string. If the current location is free, you return it. If you are not able to find a free location, you return `NULL`.

```
char *char_alloc(int s) {
  int i = 0;
  int len = 32 - s;
  while (i < len) {
    if (charheap[i] == '\0') return &charheap[i];
    i += strlen(charheap+i) + 1;
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. What confuse me is "how to return a pointer to the start of contiguous block"

Comment: Thanks for helping. That works good except for when I try to insert the third string. It just replaces the second string but not continue insert. Do you know what happen?

Comment: I think that bug was part of your original program. You actually need to skip over each previously allocated string. That means your loop logic has to be different from what you wrote.

Comment: Can you give me some hints for it? Coz I'm really confuse how to " skip over each previously allocated string" Thanks you so much.